# Generating random numbers within a specified range

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create 10 pairs of random integers within the range of [-4,+4) using PLSQL and then using the pair to solve a primary equation(num1*X+num2=0) and save the results inside the table, as well as a text output of what the type of outcome for the equation(Solvable/Indefinite/Impossible). I am using Oracle LiveSQL.

I used cursor to make sure the randomized number is an integer.

```
CURSOR NUMcursor1 IS
SELECT ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(-4,+4),0) FROM DUAL;
num1 EquatA2.dat1%TYPE; num2 EquatA2.dat2%TYPE; 
solution EquatA2.sol%TYPE; notes EquatA2.note%TYPE;
`
`
CREATE TABLE EquatA2 
(
    dat1 NUMBER(2,0),
    dat2 NUMBER(2,0),
    sol NUMBER(6,3),
    note VARCHAR2(20)
)

DECLARE
num1 EquatA2.dat1%TYPE; num2 EquatA2.dat2%TYPE; 
solution EquatA2.sol%TYPE; notes EquatA2.note%TYPE;
i INT; i:=1;

CURSOR NUMcursor1 IS
SELECT ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(-4,+4),0) FROM DUAL;

CURSOR NUMcursor2 IS
SELECT ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(-4,+4),0) FROM DUAL;

BEGIN 

OPEN NUMcursor1;
OPEN NUMcursor2;

FOR i IN 1..10
LOOP

FETCH NUMcursor1 INTO num1;
EXIT WHEN NUMcursor1%NOTFOUND;

FETCH NUMcursor2 INTO num2;
EXIT WHEN NUMcursor2%NOTFOUND;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(num1);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(num2);

IF (num1 != 0) THEN solution := -num2 / num1 AND notes := 'solvable';
ELSIF (num1 == 0 AND num2 == 0) THEN notes := 'indefinite';
ELSIF (num1 == 0 AND num2 != 0) THEN notes := 'impossible';
END IF;

INSERT INTO EquatA2 VALUES(num1,num2,solution,notes);

END LOOP;

END;
`
```

`
Expected results: 10 text outputs and the range of the random numbers to be [-4,+4)

Actual results(errors):

`ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
Invalid statement
Unsupported Command
Invalid statement
Result Set 6
ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(-4,+4),0)
-2
Download CSV
Invalid statement
Result Set 7
ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(-4,+4),0)
-3
Download CSV
ORA-06550: line 18, column 56: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following: . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset The symbol "* was inserted before "=" to continue.`

Comment: `CURSOR` is a PL/SQL declaration, so it can only exist within the declaration section of a PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified your code so that it works. Here you go.

Table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE EquatA2
  2  (
  3      dat1 NUMBER(2,0),
  4      dat2 NUMBER(2,0),
  5      sol  NUMBER(6,3),
  6      note VARCHAR2(20)
  7  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

PL/SQL anonymous procedure:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    num1     EquatA2.dat1%TYPE;
  3    num2     EquatA2.dat2%TYPE;
  4    solution EquatA2.sol%TYPE;
  5    notes    EquatA2.note%TYPE;
  6  BEGIN
  7    delete from equata2;
  8    FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
  9      num1 := ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(-4, +4), 0);
 10      num2 := ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(-4, +4), 0);
 11      -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(num1);
 12      -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(num2);
 13
 14      IF num1 != 0 THEN
 15          solution := -num2 / num1;
 16          notes := 'solvable';
 17      ELSIF num1 = 0 AND num2 = 0 THEN
 18         notes := 'indefinite';
 19      ELSIF num1 = 0 AND num2 != 0
 20        THEN notes := 'impossible';
 21      END IF;
 22
 23      INSERT INTO EquatA2 VALUES (num1, num2, solution, notes);
 24    END LOOP;
 25  END;
 26  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from equata2;

      DAT1       DAT2        SOL NOTE
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
         1         -4          4 solvable
        -1          0          0 solvable
         0          3          0 impossible
         0          2          0 impossible
         0          0          0 indefinite
         3         -1       ,333 solvable
         4          3       -,75 solvable
         1         -1          1 solvable
        -1         -2         -2 solvable
         2          3       -1,5 solvable

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```